# How to fill out a column's children from a List<String> data?

Tags: flutter

I need to make a column of data which comes from a service.

The service returns List data.

```
Column(
    children: null, // data from the `List<String> data`
),
```

How to make this?

Comment: `children: [...data.map((e) => Text('$e'))]` or `children: data.map((e) => Text('$e')).toList()` or `children: [for(e in data) Text('$e')]`

Comment: erratum: the last one should be `children: [for (var e in data) Text('$e')]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a complement to the other answer, after [Dart 2.3](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists) you can use Collection For as follows:

```
Column(
    // will be repeated for every element in myList
    children: [for (var text in myList) Text(text)], 
),
```

It is easier and cleaner as the mapping method. It also makes your code more readable.

For more information you can check [Dart's language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour).

Answer (score 4):

You can **Map** through list and return widget that you want:

```
List<String> data = ['text 1', 'text 2', 'text 3'];
Column(
  children: data.map((e) => Text(e)).toList(),
);
```

**Don't** forget to use **toList()**

Comment: for instance I have a list of data ['alpha', 'beta'], then it renders it like "alpha"  and the next line is prefixed be space " beta", why is it?

Comment: `Column(children: [for (String text in testData) Text(text)],),` where `List<String> testData = ['Alpha', 'Beta'];`

Comment: @rozerro That is not my way :) but anyway the problem is `crossAxisAlignment` for `column` by default is `center`, so just add `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start` for `Column`

Comment: @rozerro look at my latest comment